# Cannot get code after await to be executed in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

Hi been working on this for over a week now and still cannot work out why the code following the `await` doesn't get executed. Based on what I have read you would believe it's because the await is not completing but it does return Task completed="0".

What I want to achieve is to:

1. Open a .CSV file and save the data to a database (works fine)
2. Then Send an email to say the file was uploaded ok (works fine)
3. Then display on the screen in a ListView the result of the upload and email sending (Filename, Email sent ok, etc.). **This is the part that never gets executed**.

I've tried a couple of ways, but always the same result (or lack of?). The only line awaited is the one in the code below:

```
 public async Task<string[]> AutomaticFileUploadAsync()
{
   // code for uploading file data to the Database omitted for simplicity //
   // code for making a DataTable and adding data to it omitted for simplicity //

   // Send all emails //
      errorClass.writeToDebugLogFile("About to Send Email. point 2", DateTime.Now.ToString());
      Task<string[]> task1 = AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync(fileUploadDetails);
      await Task.WhenAll(task1);
      CompletedEmailTask = task1.Result;

      /*Task<string[]> completedTask = AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync(fileUploadDetails);
      CompletedEmailTask = await completedTask; // completedTask = 0 means is complete(OK), completedTask = 1 means Fault, completedTask = 2 means IsCancelled
      // do something with CompletedEmailTask here // */
       
      errorClass.writeToDebugLogFile("Just sent Email(s). point 2a", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

I've tried both the live code and the commented-out code. It writes to the DebugLog every step up to running the send email task. It never writes to DebugLog point 2a, or any following code (where it would update the Listview and display it).

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE1
The following code was omitted originally because it drills down through a few functions, till it gets to the actual awaited email sending.

```
public async Task<string[]> AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync(string[,] fileUploadStatus)
{
    int arrayGetLength = fileUploadStatus.GetLength(0); // first dimension of array
    string[] completedTask = new string[2];
    string[] completedTaskResults = new string[arrayGetLength];

    // send emails
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayGetLength; i++)
    {
        string localResKeyID = fileUploadStatus[i, 4]; // get reservationID
        
        if (localResKeyID != "")
        {
            completedTask = await SendHTMLEmailAsync(localResKeyID, localEmailType);
        }
        else
        {
            completedTask[0] = "1";
        }
        completedTaskResults[i] = completedTask[0];
    }

    return completedTaskResults;
    }
```

then

```
 protected async Task<string[]> SendHTMLEmailAsync(string bookingRef, int emailType)
{
    string[] taskException = new string[2];
    try
    {
        string imageName1 = ""; // removed for simplicity
        string imageName2 = ""; // removed for simplicity
        string imageName3 = ""; // removed for simplicity
        string imageName4 = ""; // removed for simplicity
        string imageName5 = ""; // removed for simplicity
        string imageSource1 = "\\htm\\images\\" + imageName1);
        string imageSource2 = "\\htm\\images\\" + imageName2);
        string imageSource3 = "\\htm\\images\\" + imageName3);
        string imageSource4 = "\\htm\\images\\" + imageName4);
        string imageSource5 = "\\htm\\images\\" + imageName5);
        string serverLink = (Server.MapPath("") + "\\htm\\");

        taskException = await EmailClass.SendBookingHTMLEmailAsync(imageSource1, imageSource2, imageSource3, imageSource4, imageSource5, bookingRef, serverLink, emailType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write to error log ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    return taskException;
}
```

then

```
public async Task<string[]> SendBookingHTMLEmailAsync(string imageSource1, string imageSource2, string imageSource3, string imageSource4, string imageSource5, string bookingRef, string serverLink, int emailType)
{
  var mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
  string[] taskExceptionEmail = new string[3];
  
 // removed over 2000 lines of code for simplicity from here      

  taskExceptionEmail = await EmailServCs.SendMailUsingAsync(mail);

   return taskExceptionEmail;
}
```

then

```
 public async Task<string[]> SendMailUsingAsync(MailMessage mailMessage)
{
    string mailSettingsSection = "mailSettings/Ionos";
    // make new array to store Task result
    string[] completedTask = new string[3];
    // populate array with some default data
    completedTask[0] = "99";
    completedTask[1] = "99";
    completedTask[2] = "99";
    // set whether SSL security is enabled
    bool enableSSL = true;
    
    try
    {
        if (sendEmails == true) // used to prevent email sending for debugging
        {
            SmtpSection SmtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(mailSettingsSection); // set which smtp mail settings section in web.config to use.
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpSection.Network.Host, SmtpSection.Network.Port)) // get the Host and Port name / number from Web.config
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpSection.Network.UserName, SmtpSection.Network.Password); // get the Username and Password for the account used for sending, from in Web.config
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtpClient.Timeout = 30000;

                Task task = smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage); // set a new Task to record results
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false); // set an awaiter for our new task            
                smtpClient.Dispose();
                if (task.IsFaulted == true)
                {
                    completedTask[0] = "1";
                    string TaskExceptionMsg = task.Exception.Message;
                    completedTask[1] = TaskExceptionMsg;
                }
                else if (task.IsCanceled == true)
                {
                    completedTask[0] = "2";
                    string TaskExceptionMsg = task.Exception.Message;
                    completedTask[1] = TaskExceptionMsg;
                }
                else if (task.IsCompleted == true)
                {
                    completedTask[0] = "0";
                    completedTask[1] = "Sent Ok";
                }
                else
                {
                    // something else happened
                    completedTask[0] = "error";
                    completedTask[1] = "error";
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write To ErrorLogFile ex.message
    }
    return completedTask;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't use `Task.Result`, in particular not when you already awaited the task. You should do just `CompletexEmailTask = await Task.WhenAll(task1)`.

Comment: Btw.: Why do you call `WhenAll` on a **single** task at all? Why not just `await task1`?

Comment: `errorClass.writeToDebugLogFile("Just... ` you are not rolling your own custom logging, are you?

Comment: Can you share `AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync`? Also what is type of `CompletedEmailTask`? Other than that sound like a "standard" deadlock in "classic" ASP.NET.

Comment: I wonder how `await Task.WhenAll(task1);` should ever compile, when `task1` is `Task<string[]>`. Please share `AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync` also.

Comment: You need to also post the code in AutoUploadedBookingFileEmailingCodeAsync

Comment: In answer to the 1st two replies, I used them because your suggestions are how I did it before in the commented-out section, and that didn't work, so tried something else. I'm going back to the way you suggest, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'Rolling' your own custom logging? It is custom logging that is from a Microsoft suggestion for creating your own custom logging in C#